# converting xml message to CSV in Websphere ESB

Tags: xml, csv, websphere, esb

Below is an xml structure. Here under the root tag, one element is repeating (student) and other two are non-repeating (class and classTeacher). I’m getting this xml message from a JMS queue and want to convert it to a csv file in the below format (i.e each student will come in a new line in the csv file.)

This is the flow I have created for this transformation:

JMS Export -->Fan Out --> XSLT Transformation (mapping primitiveContext/FanOutContext/occurance/student to student element in target BO) --> Flat file adapter

With this flow, for every student element a new csv file is created. But I need new csv file getting created as per each request.
The csv file will contains the rows as per the number of student elements in the request.

For example:

Input XML request

```
<students>
<class>  forth </class>  
<classTeacher>  Jhon </classTeacher> 

<student>
<name> Alex</name>
<age> 16</age>
</student>
<student>
<name> Tim</name>
<age> 15</age>
</student>

<students>
```

Output CSV format:

```
Alex , 16 ,forth, Jhon  
Tim ,15,forth, Jhon
```

Many Thanks.. Habin

Answer (score 0):

you can create a message set. for details of how to do it see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ad20808_.htm) For another example of how to map fields see the bottom answer of this [discussion](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=154442&sid=09a33496943c8bda6d96e761b747ec02)

Comment: Thanks Rachel for ur reply. I'm using websphere ESB 7.0 not message broker.In WESB I can't find message set.

Comment: @user169628 you can generate a jasper report which can then be saved as a csv see this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0411_olivieri/0411_olivieri.html